# Flask : double slash in urls

Tags: python, url, flask, slash

I'm having some trouble with Flask deployed under gunicorn + nginx. My website is under a reverse proxy to go on the url : `http://example.com/identity/`.

I have several urls in my Flask application and for each one (for example "index") :

- when I try to access to `http://example.com/identity/index/` (with the trailing slash) it goes right to the url
- when I try to access to `http://example.com/identity/index` (without the trailing slash) it goes to `http://example.com/identity//index/?` (notice the double slash and question mark).

In Flask, the route associated to `index` is : `@route('/identity/index')`. I guess my problem is a "normal" Flask behaviour but I would like to access `index` without any slash and have my normal url. Same goes with redirections using `redirect(url_for('index'))` for example.

Comment: The behaviour you see is not something Flask does, not on routes that don't end in `/` themselves. This is either your nginx configuration, gunicorn, or some middleware you are using.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer and formatting. I don't use any middleware so I will have a look at my nginx configuration. I hope gunicorn is not modifying my urls...

Comment: For people landing here from google: Nginx merges adjacent slashes by default. This can be turned off with `merge_slashes off;`, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a problem with my Nginx configuration, I was running under https from the outside and under http between my servers. So I used this snippet : http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/ to force https urls in my application and now it works !